GPU Memory increases with each re-initialization of the model
I am currently working on a ML project, in which I need to send all tensors to CUDA for training. The problem is whenever I re-define my model and send it to CUDA, GPU Memory usage increases (although the model name didn't change), and it seems that there is a memory leak which I can't free unless I restart the kernel.
for example:
if I run the following pseudocode:
my_model = model(params)
my_model.to('cuda')
my_model = model(params)
my_model.to('cuda')

the memory increases twice (once per-allocation). I tried emptying the cache as follows:
my_model.to('cpu')
torch.cuda.empty_cach()
gc.collect()`


but this only frees memory from the last allocation. Also, deleting my_model with :
del my_model
doesn't affect GPU memory.
My question is :

Why is this the case ?
How can I free that leaky memory?

I am using torch 2.2.1 with CUDA 11.8 on ubuntu 23.04

Are you running this in a notebook ?

yes I am using jupyter notebook.

Memory management in jupyter notebook is quite bad. Try if this remains in a normal python script
